# Namespace resolution result differs between VS2015 and VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

Our team uses rule "`using`s inside namespace".
There are two classes:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int CalcSomething()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace Foo
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someObj = new SomeClass();

            Console.WriteLine(someObj.CalcSomething());
        }
    }
}
```

Since `SomeClass` is in `Foo.Bar` namespace, quick actions menu is offering to resolve namespace, but result differs between VS2015:

[image]

and VS2017:

[image]

Both versions have [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) installed, if this matters. Both use appropriate PPT extension versions.

How to change resolution behavior for **VS2017**? I don't need "long namespace", because it's superfluous here.

Comment: You can apply the simplify name refactoring but I don't know that the behavior is configurable. The language service has changed in a number of ways

Comment: @AluanHaddad: it's not applicable in VS2017, unfortunately (while in VS2015 it is).